# Why do I get difference results when using pooled ols and random effects model?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, random-effects-model, pooling

I was wondering what the difference between pooled OLS and random effects model is? I know that random effects eliminates the time-constant effect.

However, when i run my regression with pooled ols and random effects model I get different results. The pooled ols regression looks find where all the variables are significant. When i run the random effects model (with the same dependent and independent variables) many of the variables get insignificant. 
The sample size is smaller for the random effects model because for some observations I only have one year which I can use in my pooled OLS regression but not in my random effects regression?

Could this be the reason why I get different results?

Comment: Is the dataset same for the two models ? and why should you drop some data!

Comment: Actually I dont have to drop observations when using Random Effects model. But even when I am using the same sample size I get different results? And yes, the sample size is the same

Comment: I presume that random effects model has certain assumptios which are different from what we have for OLS, What are these presumptions and are you trying to invoke the non-linear regression for the same dataset? This could cause a difference in the results, Certain variables are known (can be presumed) to have a non-linear effect.